# Sales vs Profit Dashboards in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to achieve a viz in Tableau in which If I click on a paramteer value called sales then sales viz should be selected and if I click on parameter value Profit, then profit viz should be displayed.

Can this be done using parameters in the first place?
Or Action filter is the only option?If action filter is the option can I make sure that If I select one parameter say Sales then the other Viz should be hidden automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this link in the tableau training tutorial which might be useful for you.

https://www.tableau.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/advanced-training-parameters

Steps to follow.

1- Create a parameter with data type "string" which will display either Profit or Sales as values.

2- Create a calculated field with case when function to link your parameter to the measures you want to use (in your case sales or profit).

`CASE [Parameter - Sales or Profit] 
WHEN 'Sales' THEN [Sales]   ## assuming your sales dimension is sales.
WHEN 'Profit' THEN [Profit]  ## assuming your profit dimension is profit.
ELSE 'Others' 
END`

This link would be helpful http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/help.htm#changing-views-using-parameters.html

3- Build your graph

4- Show Parameter control (the one you created in the first step).

Every time you update the parameter, the graph will be updated.

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: juanma thanks for the reply. ill try both methods mentioned here today

Comment: can you illustrate the calculated field part. i have to make sure that one parameter is selected, the other viz is not shown. eg if sales parameter is selected only sales viz should be shown and vice versa

Comment: Hi @Kapil Lehar. Yes, I've just updated my previous answer.

Comment: juanma thanks for the update. however i want to know how do you link the graph with the parameter ?

Comment: do you know how to work about it using action filter if not this method ?

Comment: here i have updated the workbook that im working upon and placed on tableau public. link is :
https://public.tableau.com/profile/publish/SalesvsproftbyRegion/ProfitbyRegion#!/publish-confirm

Comment: Hi. Quick question. Do you want to change the graph every time you change the parameter? If so, just change your measure in row (in your example - profit) for your new calculated field (selection calc).

Here is the workbook https://public.tableau.com/views/SalesvsproftbyRegion-Stackoverflow/ProfitbyRegion?:embed=y&:display_count=yes

Comment: just another question. can we do this with any viz? say i have to viz and i want to the graphs to change every time. In this example we hard coded sales and profit column in the calculated field

Comment: Hi @Kapil Lehar. I think as long as you link the parameter and calculated field, it should work . Do you have a specific example in mind? Currently on holiday and back in a week. Happy to help.

Comment: no example in specific. just 2 diffferent charts. say 1 is area chart and other is bubble chart. both charts depicting the same data but different chart type. can you create a parameter in such a case where you can select the chart type ?

Comment: eg of such a workbook is :

https://public.tableau.com/profile/kapillehar#!/vizhome/test_1892/Sheet2?publish=yes

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to put measure values on either the row or column shelf; and measure names on the filter shelf. The show the filter control for measure names.

The downside is that people can choose other measures that you did not intend to expose

Comment: hi alex this looks more feasible. however is there any technique that can help in this case ? is using context filter an option ? since it will restict values only to that workbook. i need to try this today

Comment: I'm not sure a context filter will help with Measure Names, but you can hide all the other measures in the data pane. You can duplicate the data source if you don't want to interfere with other worksheets.

Comment: Hi alex this shows both the profit and sales on the same chart. how do you go about managing this

Comment: Then just put Measure Names on the filter shelf and choose one measure at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with parameters. You use a layout container to hold each sheet and then the parameter will filter one and not the other.

See this post for details. http://www.bfongdata.com/2014/10/chart-creation-with-parameters.html